# Prometheus doesn't launch blackboxe's probe

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm trying to start a prometheus to monitor one web-server.
My blackbox.yml:

```
modules:
  http_2xx:
    prober: http
    http:
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
  http_post_2xx:
    prober: http
    http:
      method: POST
  tcp_connect:
    prober: tcp
  pop3s_banner:
    prober: tcp
    tcp:
      query_response:
      - expect: "^+OK"
      tls: true
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: false
  grpc:
    prober: grpc
    grpc:
      tls: true
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
  grpc_plain:
    prober: grpc
    grpc:
      tls: false
      service: "service1"
  ssh_banner:
    prober: tcp
    tcp:
      query_response:
      - expect: "^SSH-2.0-"
      - send: "SSH-2.0-blackbox-ssh-check"
  irc_banner:
    prober: tcp
    tcp:
      query_response:
      - send: "NICK prober"
      - send: "USER prober prober prober :prober"
      - expect: "PING :([^ ]+)"
        send: "PONG ${1}"
      - expect: "^:[^ ]+ 001"
  icmp:
    prober: icmp
  icmp_ttl5:
    prober: icmp
    timeout: 5s
    icmp:
      ttl: 5
```

And prometheus.yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s

scrape_configs:
- job_name: blackbox # To get metrics about the exporter itself
  metrics_path: /metrics
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - localhost:5555

- job_name: blackbox-http # To get metrics about the exporter's targets
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_2xx]
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - http://mytarget:port/test
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: localhost:5555
```

Launch commands:

```
docker run -d -p 5555:9115 --name blackbox -v `pwd`:/config prom/blackbox-exporter:master --config.file=/config/blackbox.yml
docker run -p 5556:9090 --name prometheus -v `pwd`:/config prom/prometheus --config.file=/config/prometheus.yml
```

Web-server, which I want to monitor have logs for test API. And it shows that it is not called after prometheus start.
But if I execute

```
curl 'localhost:5555/probe?target=http://mytarget:port/test&module=http_2xx'
```

then I can see that server got request and I can get metrics.

```
curl "http://localhost:5556/api/v1/label/__name__/values"
```

gives only:

```
{"status":"success","data":["scrape_duration_seconds","scrape_samples_post_metric_relabeling","scrape_samples_scraped","scrape_series_added","up"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating docker network, setting ip-addresses for containers and changing `localhost:5555` in `prometheus.yml` to `*blackbox_ip*:9115`

It was obvious after all that prometheus container can't find anything in it's `localhost:5555` but I didn't figured it out straightaway =(